# SQL Server query for getting percentage of survey selected answers

Tags: sql-server, percentage

I have made a survey in asp.net. Survey are of three types and contains different question. User have the option to select from five answers:

```
strongly agree(5), 
agree(4), 
neutral(3), 
disagree(2), 
strongly disagree(1)
```

I am getting the results in the following form.

[image: survey results in database]

I want to show results in the following form.

[image]

My question is what will the SQL query to get percentage of each selected answer starting from strong disagree to strongly agree as shown in above figure.

Comment: why in your expected result, first and second row have the total percentage 110% not 100%? is there any specific requirement?

Comment: Its the dummy percentage shown there, actual results will not exceed100% and depends on users selected answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
select sq.QuestionId,sq.QuestionText, count(ca.AnswerOptionScore) as TotalAnswered,

sum(case when ca.AnswerOptionScore=5 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), count(ca.AnswerOptionScore)) as 'StronglyAgreePercent',

sum(case when ca.AnswerOptionScore=4 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), count(ca.AnswerOptionScore)) as 'AgreePercent',

sum(case when ca.AnswerOptionScore=3 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), count(ca.AnswerOptionScore)) as 'NeutralPercent',

sum(case when ca.AnswerOptionScore=2 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), count(ca.AnswerOptionScore)) as 'DisagreePercent',

sum(case when ca.AnswerOptionScore=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), count(ca.AnswerOptionScore)) as 'StronglyDisagreePercent'

from Suvey_Completed_Answers ca

inner join Survey_Questions sq on sq.QuestionId = ca.QuestionID
 Where ca.SurveyId = 3

group by sq.QuestionText,sq.QuestionText,sq.QuestionId
```